# How to switch css files according to devices and button click?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, mobile, cookies, responsive

I am trying to enqueue a responsive css file if the website is opened on mobile devices.

Also I want to switch / enqueue a default or non-responsive css file when a button is clicked.
The non-responsive css file is the default style sheet which is loaded on desktop.

So the requirements are:

1. By default a non-responsive site should be loaded if the user from
   desktop
2. By default a responsive site should be loaded if the user from
   mobile
3. If the user clicks a desktop switching button from mobile
   (responsive) site, the non-responsive site should be loaded in the
   mobile.
4. If the user clicks a mobile switching button from mobile
   (non-responsive) site, the responsive site should be loaded.

I have `style.css` (non-responsive css file) into my theme directory and my `responsive css` file is in a folder which is into the theme directory.

- non-responsive css is file in : **theme-directory/style.css**
- responsive css is file in : **theme-directory/css/responsive.css**

And I have following buttons.

```
<div class="cr-athavan-lang-image">
    <a href="?site=mobile" class="mobile_site" id="mobile_site"><img src="file/path/to/img" alt="switch to mobile site"></a>
    <a href="?site=desktop" class="desktop_site"><img src="file/path/to/img" alt="switch to desktop site"></a>  
</div>
```

I have added following code into my `functions.php`

**A**. To load responsive site if the user from mobile:

```
 if ( wp_is_mobile() ){
        function responsive_css(){
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'wpa_custom',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css'
            );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'responsive_css', 999 );
    }
```

**B.** To load the non-responsive site if the user clicks the button

```
function switch_css_file(){
    if ($site == 'desktop'){
        function default_css(){
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'default_css',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
            );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'default_css', 999 );
    }
    if ($site == 'mobile'){
        function default_css(){
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'default_css',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css'
            );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'default_css', 999 );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'switch_css_file', 2);
```

Now requirement 1 and 2 are ok.

1. By default a non-responsive site is loaded if the user from desktop
2. By default a responsive site is loaded if the user from mobile

I am not sure the function `switch_css_file` works or NOT.
3rd and 4th requirements are not achieved yet.
If I click the `desktop_site` button from the mobile the site is reloaded and still it's in responsive version.

How can I achieve 3rd & 4th requirement?

Also I think I have to set cookie during the switching.
A cookie need to be set when the `desktop_site` button is clicked and should be unset when the `mobile_site` is clicked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**01.**
Change

```
if (($site == 'desktop'){ // code line }
```

TO

```
if (($site == 'desktop') && (wp_is_mobile())) { // code line }
```

**02.**
and for unset the cookie while the browser is closed give the time as 0 (zero) or blank.
some thing like this.

```
setcookie( 'button_clicked', $_GET['button_clicked'], 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```